# How do I flip the first number in the string with the last number and then second and second last and so on?

Tags: c++

Here's what I tried and it's not logical. First_num++ is just copying 2 numbers instead of the second number and so is the last_num++
How do I continue copying like that and cout them
I know I can just cout the thing in reverse because the output is the same.I can do that by reversing the count but the question wants me to exchange the characters one by one. Please help, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

void reverse_word(char character[]);

int main()
{
    char characters[50];
    reverse_word(characters);
    return 0;
}

void reverse_word(char character[])
{
    char temp1[2] = "\0";
    char temp2[2] = "\0";
    char first_num = 1;
    char last_num = 1;
    cout << "Enter a word to reverse first word last word second first second last and so on: ";
    cin >> character;
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(character)/2;i++)
    {
        strncpy(temp1, character, first_num);
        first_num++;
        strcpy(temp2 , &character[strlen(character)-last_num]);
        last_num++;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(character) / 2; i++)
    {
        cout << temp2;
        cout << temp1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This must be one of countless meaningless puzzles from some online coding/hacking/competition site. Unfortunately, those useless sites are nothing more than a collection of puzzles, and don't really have any material that teaches various C++ techniques and algorithms that are needed to implement these basic algorithms efficiently. That can only be found in a good C++ textbook. The shown code is much longer and complex than it needs to be. There are no quick fixes here. The entire approach is wrong, and must be reimplemented, from scratch, using appropriate algorithms and C++ library functions.

Comment: this is my university question

Comment: If your university class teaches you to use `strlen`, `strncpy` and other ancient C library functions -- as well as unsafe programming practices like plain arrays, with no bounds checking for buffer overruns -- to write modern C++ code, instead of using `std::string` and the appropriate algorithms from the C++ library, then something is seriously wrong with your university.

Comment: My lecturer said std is good but it's not needed for programs that doesn't have a lot of c preprocessor directive or something it's for our convinience for now. For the ancient c library I don't really know my university is ranking no2 in my entire country

Comment: @RyanTan -- *said std is good but it's not needed for programs that doesn't have a lot of c preprocessor directive* -- If that was truly stated, your lecturer is a `C` programmer masquerading as a C++ teacher, IMO.  Also, your description of what you want to do is confusing.  What is the actual question you are trying to answer?

Comment: I can assure you that you are not the first one to post evidence, on Stackoverflow, of having an incompetent C++ instructor. There is no good solution here, unfortunately, except to attempt to learn C++ by yourself, using a quality, edited textbook.

Comment: @RyanTan Also, if the issue is with `reverse_word2`, why are you posting irrelevant functions such as `reverse_word` and other functions?  The ideal program would be a simple `main()` program, that calls `reverse_word2` with sample data that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: This is the question. 3. Write and test a function reverse_word that has a string parameter. The function reverses the letters in the string. The program should perform the following to exchange the first and last characters in the string:

(i) Copy the first character of the string to a temporary variable.
(i) Copy the first character of the string to a temporary variable.
(ii) Copy the last character to the first position in the string.
(iii) Copy the character in the temporary variable to the last character position in the string.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary functions from the code so it should be clearer for anyone to see

Comment: @RyanTan You've been given a very detailed description of what to write, but your code is not similar to that description in any way. It should not read any input; "Copy the first character of the string to a temporary variable" looks like this `char temp = the_string[0];`; Et cetera.

Comment: @molbdnilo this method means I cout the numbers in the flipped order manually?

Comment: @RyanTan No. You should not read any input or write any output. You should rearrrange the characters that are in the array argument. ("[...] a function reverse_word that has a string parameter. The function reverses the letters in the string" does not mean "A function reverse_word that reads a string from the console and prints it in reverse".)

Comment: @molbdnilo ya I meant that just can't explain my thoughts correctly I will try that now

Comment: As test cases, `int main() { char s[] = "abc"; reverse_word(s);}` should take no input and not print anything. `int main() { char s[] = "abc"; reverse_word(s); std::cout << s;}` should should not take any input and output `cba`, nothing else. (And there are no numbers involved.)

Comment: @molbdnilo oh ok now I understood what you really meant thx for your help

Comment: thank you everyone for all the help

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Actually this is my first year and this course is programming and problem solving is all this approach for beginners to catch up easier or it should not be taught like this? About all these puzzles in my practical is it good brainstorming or just wasting time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build-in function of c++ `reverse(begin, end)` where the `begin` and `end` iterator are as parameter like below:

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    string str = "String example"; 
    reverse(str.begin(), str.end()); // outputs --> elpmaxe gnirtS 
    cout<<"\n"<<str; 
    return 0;
}
```

This is a short and fast solution , but if you want to get a more depth view you can apply some nice alogrithm .

Answer (score 0):

You should cout the temp variables in the same for loop, not in a different one.